# Laravel elequent ORM not working when migrate from mysql to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, laravel, orm, postgresql-9.1, eloquent

The Basic feature of an ORM normally says as the DB migration is easily possible from one database to another. Here I have used MySQL database for my project initially and plan to migrate this to PostgreSQL. When migrating, it works almost all simple queries with select * from table, insert update etc.

But when I come through the some `datediff` function in MySQL, the ORM fails to create corresponding queries in PostgreSQL.

Here is my query

```
$result = DB::table('sales_target')
                ->select(db::raw('DATEDIFF(end_date,start_date) as DaysInQuarter'))
                ->whereraw("sales_target.target_quarter=$currentQuarter AND sales_target.target_year=$currentYear and status=1")
                ->first();
```

I wonder whether I have written the query in completely ORM structure or not. Please help me out on this.

**Edit 1**

n short i want to anybody tell me how i can write this query

```
DB::table('sales_target')
                ->select(db::raw("DATEDIFF(end_date,start_date) AS DaysInQuarter"))
                ->first();
```

which should work in both mysql and postgresl using ORM.

In Mysql it's working correctly but in postgresql it's not.

I am getting an error like this

```
 No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select DATEDIFF(end_date,start_date) AS DaysInQuarter from "sales_target" limit 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can manage the query by writing like this

```
DB::table('sales_target')
                ->select(db::raw(" DATE_PART('day', end_date - start_date) AS DaysInQuarter"))
                ->whereRaw("sales_target.target_quarter=? AND sales_target.target_year= ? and status=1", [$currentQuarter, $currentYear])
                ->first();
```

I think in eloquent we have to manually change the function DATEDIFF to DATE_PART. But in ORM like hibernate i think they itself managing this function change in different SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't use ORM here. You are using query builder and not Eloquent.

Second thing is that Laravel won't do the job for you - if you are using raw expressions, you should use them according to db engine you use.

In addition, you should care about SQL injections, now it's possible to inject some code into your query, you should use:

```
$result = DB::table('sales_target')
                ->select(db::raw('DATEDIFF(end_date,start_date) as DaysInQuarter'))
                ->whereRaw("sales_target.target_quarter=? AND sales_target.target_year= ? and status=1", [$currentQuarter, $currentYear])
                ->first();
```

Of course in above case probably `$currentQuarter` and `$currentYear` are variables you fully control, but it's better to use prepared statemnts in case you decide later use user-input data.

Comment: Isn't query builder also based on eloquent? Aren't their  functions are interchangeable (I can use each DB function in an eloquent querry) ? I agree that Db::raw is not in any way  ORM 
Please take into consideration that I'm just in learning mode when I ask this :)

Comment: No, Eloquent is using query builder, but query builder does not use Eloquent. In above you use query builder because you start with `DB::table('sales_target')` - if you started with your model `SalesTarget` then you would use Eloquent

Comment: I am basically plan to migrate from mysql to postgresql but postgresql does not support datediff function. SO i think i cannot access db::raw('datedifff()') function. How i can manage an ORM query that will work on both mysql and postgres in the case of elequent ORM.

Comment: @anoop If you want to use your code working in any db engine, first of all don't use specific SQL functions. In above case just get end_date and start_date from database without using `datediff` and if you want to calculate difference do it in PHP

Comment: That is what i am confused about, how can i convert this to ORM DB::table('sales_target')
                ->select(db::raw('DATEDIFF(end_date,start_date) as DaysInQuarter'))
                ->whereraw("sales_target.target_quarter=$currentQuarter AND sales_target.target_year=$currentYear and status=1")
                ->first();. I am stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `db::raw()` then the ORM can’t help you abstracting from the databases engines. You should have a look at the [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com) integration in Laravel and [methods of the Query Builder like `whereBetween()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses) to rewrite your query.

Answer (score 0):

When you use "db::raw(" then this is no more ORM.

You just send that string direct to the database server exactly as it is.

Check if Postgresql have the same syntax for DateDIFF function